# Is it possible to have 2 applications that both use subdomains on the same server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Before I start I know I can have 2 apps on the same server. The goal is to have 2 applications with their own subdomains that both use application level subdomains on the same server. (I dont have a better way of wording that. Please see below.) I am using Rails 4 and Nginx on Ubuntu.

Application 1: https://sandbox.myapp.com

possible variations of the app url: https://account1.sandbox.myapp.com
https://account2.sandbox.myapp.com

Application 2: https://development.myapp.com
possible variations of the app url https://account1.sandbox.myapp.com https://account2.sandbox.myapp.com

This is what I have so far.

```
 # nginx.conf
 ...
  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name staging.myapp.com *.staging.myapp.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name sandbox.myapp.com *.sandbox.myapp.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sandbox.myapp.com *.sandbox.myapp.com;
    root /root/to/sandbox/app;
    ...
  }

  server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name demo.myapp.com *.demo.myapp.com;
    root /root/to/demo/app;
    ...
  }
```

demo.myapp.com redirects to account1.myapp.com

sandbox.myapp.com redirects to account1.myapp.com

myapp.com redirects to account1.myapp.com

I am a little confused by the result. Rails is using devise which assigns the users account name to the subdomain. I have a feeling that the subdomain is being overwritten by rails.

In the application I see a lot of:

```
 request_host = "#{account.subdomain}.#{request.host}/"
```

Does request.host not return the subdomain described in Nginx?

Comment: It sounds like you should establish what the rails side of things is doing - without it your question isn't complete

Comment: Rather than asking what the value of request.host is, add some logging to your app so that you can see exactly what these values are and what transformations your app is doing.

Comment: I am not exactly sure if this helps but when I was trying to do this I needed to modify my hosts.etc file to allow mysubdomain.localhost:3000 to resolve to localhost:3000